# Solving $\int \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{w^2-x^2}dx$

Tags: integration

I'm trying to find the antiderivative for

$$ \frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{w^2-x^2}$$ 
with respect to x.

If I use substitution: $u=w^2-x^2$, the it just make the problem harder.

If I use partial integration the problem also get harder.

Which integration technique should I use? 
Actually Maple is allowed but it is nice to know how to solve it.

Kind regards,

Comment: I'd suggest [trigonometric substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution)

Comment: Thanks. Now I know what to google for.

Comment: Try to put $x = w\sin(u)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\int\frac{2}{\pi}\sqrt{w^2-x^2}dx=\int\frac{2w}{\pi}\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{w^2}}dx$$
then let $\frac{x}{w}=\sin u$

Answer (score 1):

Set

$$x = \omega\sin\theta$$ 
$$\text{d}x = \omega\cos\theta\text{d}\theta$$

In order to make the integral

$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int \sqrt{\omega^2(1 - \sin^2\theta)}\omega\cos\theta\text{d}\theta$$

That is

$$\frac{2\omega^2}{\pi}\int\cos^2\theta\ \text{d}\theta$$

The integral is an easy one, leading to

$$\frac{2\omega^2}{\pi}\left(\frac{\theta}{2}+\frac{1}{4} \sin (2\theta)\right)$$

Then you can go back to $x$.

Comment: In which kind of course does someone learn this kind of stuff?

Comment: @Xenusi Every Analysis 1 course teaches about the so called method of "integration by substitution" ! In this case "trigonometric substitution" is the key.

Comment: Alright, thanks.